# Retain the original quality of image after using htm2canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, html2canvas

I am using [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) library to get image from a div. The div contains collection of image in masonry. All the images are in 300 dpi but the html2canvas produces output in 72 dpi.
Is there any way I can retain the 300 dpi image quality in the output from html2canvas?

```js
 html2canvas($("#collage-preview-box"), {
                    onrendered: function (canvas) {
                        cartImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png",1);
                        $("#image-show").attr('src',cartImage);
                        $('.loader').remove();

                    }
                });

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="image-part-inner">
   <div id="collage-preview-box" style="position: relative; height: 366.7px;">
      <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
      <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0px;"><img class="imgcol convert-img" data-effect="" src="http://localhost/luxe-wall/wp-content/themes/luxe_walls/vendor/fineuploader/php-traditional-server/files/733705f4-15af-4dc0-a7ab-7d497a540c8e/file.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 33.3333%; top: 0px;"><img class="imgcol convert-img" data-effect="" src="http://localhost/luxe-wall/wp-content/themes/luxe_walls/vendor/fineuploader/php-traditional-server/files/5d310f47-38ba-43ab-8e68-fbed9493a053/file.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 66.6667%; top: 0px;"><img class="imgcol convert-img" data-effect="" src="http://localhost/luxe-wall/wp-content/themes/luxe_walls/vendor/fineuploader/php-traditional-server/files/9810a0f1-63a1-46f0-91fd-5e28d6c0d943/file.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 183px;"><img class="imgcol convert-img" data-effect="" src="http://localhost/luxe-wall/wp-content/themes/luxe_walls/vendor/fineuploader/php-traditional-server/files/d73075cf-ef6d-4c9f-8f72-3f63bbde50b4/file.jpg"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The library takes a screenshot of a web page, am I right? In this case it simply takes your images in the size you see on the screen and you get a screenshot. It doesn't any image retrieving by its url. By the way, I don't understand why wouldn't it be easier to just get image url?

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich user have already set those images in layouts such as masonry or image grid which needs to be captured and converted to PDF for printing. Suggest me to achieve this if  there's any other way around?

Comment: Of course there is always a workaround. Could you please provide me a page sample with this masonry? I might write you an exact solution, code.

Comment: Below is sample image for my image editor and final preview after taking screenshot https://naphix.com.au/clients/wordpress/editor.png, https://naphix.com.au/clients/wordpress/preview.png this is 72 dpi images generated after converting div from first image into canvas.

Comment: I meant an html code of a page.

Comment: Actually, `collage-preview-box` div content is the most important to solve you problem:)

Comment: Thanks, I see. I will try to come up with a solution.

Comment: Let's try to use property http://www.cssportal.com/css-properties/image-resolution.php. Does it help you?

Comment: not at all.. the problem is with screenshot taken from the browser which captures image in 72 dpi, the css property will not do anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133877/discussion-between-dmitry-senkovich-and-saw-rov).

Comment: Where did you get the value of 72 DPI & 300 DPI. This is meaningless for anything but print, you can easily make the image 300DPI by reducing the print size. You must be more specific. What is the intended print size,(if any) of this image, or is it just a pdf for electronic distribution?.

Answer (score 1):

DPI is for print. Images have resolution, their DPI depends on how large or small you print them. To get an image of the correct resolution to print at a desired DPI you must know what size the print will be.

A PDF is typically presented as A4 portrait. A full A4 page is 8.27 × 11.69 inches which at 72 DPI is 595 by 842 pixels. For 300 DPI the image resolution is 2482 by 3508.

It is easy to set the size of the html2Canvas image

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  },
  width: 2482,
  height: 3508
});
```

Which will result in an image that is 300DPI when printed on a A4 sheet.

The problem is you need to increase the page size to fit that image.

Just create a container element with the width and height set 2482 by 3508. Add the images and what not to that element at the correct size to fit the large format.

```
<div class="image-part-inner" style='width:2482px;height:3508px'>
   <div id="collage-preview-box" style="position: relative; height: 366.7px;">
      <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
      <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0px;"><img class="imgcol convert-img" data-effect="" src="http://localhost/luxe-wall/wp-content/themes/luxe_walls/vendor/fineuploader/php-traditional-server/files/733705f4-15af-4dc0-a7ab-7d497a540c8e/file.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 33.3333%; top: 0px;"><img class="imgcol convert-img" data-effect="" src="http://localhost/luxe-wall/wp-content/themes/luxe_walls/vendor/fineuploader/php-traditional-server/files/5d310f47-38ba-43ab-8e68-fbed9493a053/file.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 66.6667%; top: 0px;"><img class="imgcol convert-img" data-effect="" src="http://localhost/luxe-wall/wp-content/themes/luxe_walls/vendor/fineuploader/php-traditional-server/files/9810a0f1-63a1-46f0-91fd-5e28d6c0d943/file.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 183px;"><img class="imgcol convert-img" data-effect="" src="http://localhost/luxe-wall/wp-content/themes/luxe_walls/vendor/fineuploader/php-traditional-server/files/d73075cf-ef6d-4c9f-8f72-3f63bbde50b4/file.jpg"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then just call html2Canvas to get the image

```
html2canvas(".image-part-inner", {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
     // do whatever you do with the image.
  },
  width: 2482,
  height: 3508
});
```

And you have an image that is 300 DPI if printed on an A4 page. If printed on a A3 page the DPI will be 150 DPI and on a A5 600 DPI. But the resolution will always be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Blindman67 . Actually, I need this to convert this image to PDF and send it to print for wallpapers. This is working but ther are two problems 1) I need to show the preview of the image grid in browser which is not possible at this size and 2) browser goes unresponsive when I try to create a PDF from this size.

Comment: @Saw.Rov  You can set the canvas style width and height for the preview to whatever size you need. Eg `onrendered: function(canvas) { canvas.style.width = '1024px'; canvas.style.height = '840px'; ...` then add it for preview.  Dont use `canvas.toDataURL` just display the canvas, the canvas is a HTMLImageElement just like the <img> element so there is no need to create the huge and very wasteful dataURL (over 50% of dataURL bits are not used and just chew up RAM, plus the image's pixel buffer, will make most browsers sluggish)

Comment: everything works well, Thanks for the help. There is one problem though, I have made one large frame with style='width:2482px;height:3508px' (this is hidden) and kept smaller one for user preview. But html2canvas only captures the portion that is visible in the window from the large frame. Is there any way so that I can get the full large frame without being cut off in canvas?